# img onclick call to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a img that when it is clicked a JavaScript function is called.

I have searched on the web but haven't found anything that actually works (prob because of a mistake I made).

This code was made to pass JavaScript variables to a c# application.

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function exportToForm(a,b,c,d,e) {
          window.external.values(a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value, e.value);
      }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img onclick="exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1');" src="China-Flag-256.png"/>
  <button onclick="exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1');" style="background-color: #00FFFF">Export</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What is it about your code that is not working? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Place your javascript code in <script type="text/javascript"> tag

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: @Murali srry allready have that

Comment: window.external.values(a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value, e.value);
Here, a.value is wrong. a is string which don't have value atribue
And, make sure 'values' function exist

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This should work(with or without 'javascript:' part):

```
<img onclick="javascript:exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1')" src="China-Flag-256.png" />
<script>
function exportToForm(a, b, c, d, e) {
     alert(a, b);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: needed to wait for it to be possible

Comment: does it matter if the script is before or after the img?

Comment: It is better to place the script before the </body> tag or as close to it as possible.  You can test in jsfiddle to place it before and after img tag. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 6):

You should probably be using a more [unobtrusive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) approach. Here's the benefits

> - Separation of functionality (the "behavior layer") from a Web page's structure/content and presentation
> - Best practices to avoid the problems of traditional JavaScript programming (such as browser inconsistencies and lack of scalability)
> - Progressive enhancement to support user agents that may not support advanced JavaScript functionality

[Here's a jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8N4ep/1/)

Your JavaScript

```js
function exportToForm(a, b, c, d, e) {
  console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i=0, len=images.length, img; i<len; i++) {
  img = images[i];
  img.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var a = img.getAttribute("data-a"),
        b = img.getAttribute("data-b"),
        c = img.getAttribute("data-c"),
        d = img.getAttribute("data-d"),
        e = img.getAttribute("data-e");

    exportToForm(a, b, c, d, e);
  });
}
```

Your images will look like this

```html
<img data-a="1" data-b="2" data-c="3" data-d="4" data-e="5" src="image.jpg">
```

Comment: I love this solution but for me it didn't work. The problem is that you've got the variable values of the latest value img. You have to bind the attribute values to the function.

Answer (score 1):

Put the javascript part and the end right before the closing `</body>` then it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q3Zy3/1/

```
  <img onclick="exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1');" src="China-Flag-256.png"/>
  <button onclick="exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1');" style="background-color: #00FFFF">Export</button>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      function exportToForm(a,b,c,d,e) {
      alert(a + b);
      window.external.values(a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value, e.value);
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your onclick function works absolutely fine its your this line
`window.external.values(a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value, e.value);`

window.external is object and has no method name values

```
<html>
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript">
          function exportToForm(a,b,c,d,e) {
             // window.external.values(a.value, b.value, c.value, d.value, e.value);
          //use alert to check its working 
         alert("HELLO");
}
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <img onclick="exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1');" src="China-Flag-256.png"/>
      <button onclick="exportToForm('1.6','55','10','50','1');" style="background-color: #00FFFF">Export</button>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to the good solution from maček. The solution didn't work for me. I have to bind the values of the datas to the export function. This solution works for me:

```
function exportToForm(a, b, c, d, e) {
  console.log(a, b, c, d, e);
}

var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i=0, len=images.length, img; i<len; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  var boundExportToForm = exportToForm.bind(undefined, 
          img.getAttribute("data-a"), 
            img.getAttribute("data-b"),
            img.getAttribute("data-c"),
            img.getAttribute("data-d"),
            img.getAttribute("data-e"))

  img.addEventListener("click", boundExportToForm);
  }
```